# Clarification on assassinations in the film Looper

Tags: looper

When the main character's money ran out when he was in China, he did freelance assassination jobs to cover his expenses; in the near future where, "disposing of bodies" is  near impossible to be kept secretly. What would be the difference between time-travel assassinations and daylight assassinations if syndicates and freelance assassins still kill openly in the future? Like when they killed main character's wife? I don't see the purpose of sending people to the past if they still do open killings in the future.